# Cannot use SignalR / Hub class in Blazor WebAssembly project

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr, blazor-webassembly, signalr-hub

I created a new Blazor WebAssembly project (target framework: .NET 8.0, SDK and hosting bundle installed) and wanted to add Hub features to communicate with other clients, but I am stuck quite early: Neither the extension method AddSignalR() nor the type Hub is available.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Spire;
using Spire.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ISessionData>(sessiondata => new SessionData());
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMainData>(mainData => new MainData());

        builder.Services.AddSignalR(); // <- not working

        WebAssemblyHost app = builder.Build();
        await app.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Obviously, I am missing some package, but it does not seem to be obvious which one is the right. These packages I tried:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
    
        <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazor.Extensions.Canvas" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="8.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common" Version="8.0.0" />  
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out that it's somehow related to the project's Sdk property (the project type you chose in VS).

"Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly" (project type "Blazor Webassembly Standalone App") doesn't introduce the things I missed, while "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" (project type "Blazor Web App") does.

Comment: I assume you wanted to host the SignalR Hub on the server side of your Blazor application? The SignalR Hub class is available in a standard Core Web project without adding a new package.